# Coding a AMQP listening and user-facing daemon in Python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, twisted, amqp, openstack

Edit: I posted this to python-list and tutor-list with no responses. Any advice would be much appreciated.

What is the best approach to writing a concurrent daemon that can execute callbacks for different types of events (AMQP messages, parsed output of a subprocess, HTTP requests)?

I am considering [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation), the built-in [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module, and [greenlet](http://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I must admit that I am very unfamiliar with concurrent programming and Python programming in general (formerly a data analysis driven procedural programmer). Any resources on threaded/concurrent programming (specifically daemons...not just multi-threading a single task) would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Details:

1) Listens into AMQP messaging queues and executes callbacks when messages arrive.
Example: Immediately after startup, the daemon continuously listens to the [Openstack Notifications messaging queue](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/NotificationEventExamples#Immediate_Notifications%3a). When a virtual machine is launched, a notification is generated by Openstack with the hostname, IP address, etc. The daemon should read this message and write some info to a log (or POST the info to a server, or notify the user...something simple).

2) Parse the output of a subprocess and execute callbacks based on the output.
Example: Every 30 seconds, a system command "[qstat](http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/commands/qstat.shtml)" is run to query a job resource manager (e.g. TORQUE). Similar callbacks to 1).

3) Receive requests from a user and process them. I think this will be via WSGI HTTP.
Example: User submits an XML template with virtual machine templates. The daemon does some simple XML parsing and writes a job script for the job resource manager. The job is submitted to the resource manager and the daemon continually checks for the status of the job with "qstat" and for messages from AMQP. It should return "live" feedback to the user and write to a log.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the OpenStack Oslo project.

Start here:

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Oslo

Oslo is basically a shared resource for all OpenStack applications.  The focus here is providing re-usable code, and standardizing on methods that many applications create or use.

Messaging being a fundamental component of OpenStack has some break outs.  Also, since openstack supports many messaging protocols, maybe doing direct AMQP isn't the right answer for you.

Anyways check this...

Messaging Specifically is being placed here:

https://github.com/openstack/oslo.messaging

I'd go dig into that repository and play with some of the methods made available there.